# Cannot delete or getOrCreate sparkContext in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

this is my first time trying to use spark for machine learning, and I was planning to use it in Jupyter Notebook.

It seems like I ran into a problem of instantiating spark in a wrong way.. Apparently I can only instantiate one sparkContext.

I have tried

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import  SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

and

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import  SparkContext
sc = sc.stop()
```

Which were two common solutions that were posted.

If i do not instantiate `sc`, then `sc` will be an unidentified object. 
So if I instantiate it by `.sparkContext()`, it tells me that I cannot have multiple spark context - I am not sure where to find my existing spark context somewhere on my laptop,  or how to solve this issue without even knowing what to call this object.

I also closed all my terminals (except the one to keep Jupyter Notebook open) because I once typed `$pyspark` there to check if it was properly installed.

Here is my error message:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-eca205ca2337> in <module>
      2 findspark.init()
      3 from pyspark import  SparkContext
----> 4 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    365         with SparkContext._lock:
    366             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 367                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    368             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    369 

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    134         try:
    135             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 136                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    137         except:
    138             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    196 
    197         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 198         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    199         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    200         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    304         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    305         """
--> 306         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    307 
    308     @classmethod

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1523         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1524         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1526 
   1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2483)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2479)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.assertNoOtherContextIsRunning(SparkContext.scala:2479)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.markPartiallyConstructed(SparkContext.scala:2568)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could anyone advice me with how to fix this issue so that I can instantiate a new sparkContext and proceed with my project?  Thank you very much!!!